# Initializing Multiple PHP Variables Simultaneously

Tags: php

How may I initialize multiple PHP variables with a value of zero  simultaneously *without using an array*? I wish to write code that is essentially equivalent to the following:

```
$first = 0;
$second = 0;
$third = 0;
$fourth = 0;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign same value to multiple variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651594/assign-same-value-to-multiple-variables)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
$first = $second = $third = $fourth = 0;
```

Comment: Doesn't this run into the problem that when you change $fourth, you also change the rest?

Comment: If you change `$fourth`, you won't change the rest, because `0` is a value, not a reference. If you would have done something like `$fourth = 0; $third = &$fourth; $second = &$fourth; $first = &$fourth`, then all the other variables would be references to `$fourth` (not the value `0`), and changing `$fourth` would be reflected in the other variables as well.

Comment: This multiple assignment works because, in PHP, assignment is an expression which returns the assigned value. Thus, `$fourth = 0` is an expression which returns the value `0`. This value is then assigned to `$third`, and, since this assignment is also an expression, the return value of assigning `0` to `$third` is again the value `0`, etc.

Answer (score 23):

While it is feasible to initialize multiple variables using a comma operator within a for-loop, as follows:

```
<?php
for ($a=0,$b=0,$c=0,$d=0;;) {
    break;
}
var_dump($a,$b,$c,$d);
```

(See demo [here](https://3v4l.org/t7V7e#output))

the **list** construct provides a more efficient way to perform multiple variable assignment, as depicted in the following example:

```
<?php

list( $first, $second, $third, $fourth ) = array( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
var_dump($first, $second, $third, $fourth );
```

See demo [here](https://3v4l.org/9C4NK)

One may wish to reconsider avoiding the usage of arrays to achieve multiple initialized variables. With PHP7.1+ one may write simpler, robust code if one utilizes [array destructuring](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax) available with short array syntax, as follows:

```
<?php

[$first, $second, $third, $fourth ] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
var_dump($first, $second, $third, $fourth );
```

See demo [here](https://3v4l.org/O10SJ#output).

If one needs to be certain that the variables being initialized were not previously set, see this related [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025250/proper-way-to-declare-multiple-vars-in-php), particularly this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025250/proper-way-to-declare-multiple-vars-in-php/11025283#11025283).

Comment: You can use this method for declaring multiple variables with different values, and that makes this far more useful.

Comment: @Alec This is a bit confusing for declaring variables with different values.

Answer (score 2):

> **If you want to initialize multiple array variables then use**

```
# Initialize multiple array variables with Empty values
$array_1 = $array_2 = $array_3 = array();

# Initialize multiple array variables with Some values in it
list( $array_1, $array_2, $array_3) = array('one','two','three');

# Print value of array variables
var_dump($array_1,$array_2,$array_3);

Output:
*******
string 'one' (length=3)
string 'two' (length=3)
string 'three' (length=5)
```

> **If you want to initialize multiple regular variables then use**

```
# Initialize multiple regular variables with values
$a = $b = $c = 'Hello PHP';
echo $a.'<br>',$b.'<br>', $c.'<br>';

Output:
*******
Hello PHP
Hello PHP
Hello PHP
```