# Assign same value to multiple variables at once?

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

How can I assign the same value for multiple variables in PHP at once ?

I have something like:

```
$var_a = 'A';
$var_b = 'A';
$same_var = 'A';
$var_d = 'A';
$some_var ='A';
```

In my case, I can't rename all variables to have the same name (that would make things more easy), so is there any way to assign the same value to all variables in a much more compact way?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

```
$var_a = $var_b = $same_var = $var_d = $some_var = 'A';
```

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfect for me

    $level1 = $level2 = $level3 = $level4 = false;

Comment: This can't be used in Php class and this is the raw type.

Comment: @ChamindaBandara what do you mean it cannot be used in a PHP class?

Comment: @Eoin: In doing `$var_a = $var_b = ... = new Class();`, all the variables will reference the same instance of `Class`.

Comment: @Eoin That means, this syntax working only for PHP server side scripts and it's not working for Object Orient programming in PHP. If you use this method within a PHP class, you will get an error.

Comment: Is it this syntax PSR compliant?

Answer (score 11):

To add to the other answer.

`$a = $b = $c = $d` 
actually means `$a = ( $b = ( $c = $d ) )`

PHP passes primitive types `int, string, etc.` by value and objects by reference ***by default.***

That means

```
$c = 1234;
$a = $b = $c;
$c = 5678;
//$a and $b = 1234; $c = 5678;

$c = new Object();
$c->property = 1234;
$a = $b = $c;
$c->property = 5678;
// $a,b,c->property = 5678 because they are all referenced to same variable
```

However, you CAN pass objects by value too, using keyword `clone`, but you will have to use parenthesis.

```
$c = new Object();
$c->property = 1234;
$a = clone ($b = clone $c);
$c->property = 5678;
// $a,b->property = 1234; c->property = 5678 because they are cloned
```

BUT, you CAN NOT pass primitive types by reference with keyword `&`  ***using this method***

```
$c = 1234;

$a = $b = &$c; // no syntax error
// $a is passed by value. $b is passed by reference of $c

$a = &$b = &$c; // syntax error

$a = &($b = &$c); // $b = &$c is okay. 
// but $a = &(...) is error because you can not pass by reference on value (you need variable)

// You will have to do manually
$b = &$c;
$a = &$b;
etc.
```