# What multiple = mean in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to understand the code in [**this**](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader) open source from GitHub.
However, I find this very unusual line of code that I never see it before. (in getvideo.php line 150).

```
$thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';
```

What are those **=** in `$variable = $variable = $variable = $variable` doing and what is it called?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651594/assign-same-value-to-multiple-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means, its assigning all variables to NULL;

```
$thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';
```

in other words

```
$thumbnail_url ='';
$title ='';
$url_encoded_fmt_stream_map='';
$type='';
$url = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

In most languages (including PHP) writing...

```
a = b = c = d;
```

is the same as writing

```
a = (b = (c = d));
```

which is the same as writing

```
c = d;
b = d;
a = d;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just the "assignment" operator. When in succession, it just means that they all assigned to the final result (in this case, an empty string).

Comment: No, this is the *assignment* operator. The "equals" or "equality" operator is `==`.

Comment: By the way: I think it's called multi-variable assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`$thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';`

means emptying all the variables