# Set and export multiple environment variables to the same value in bash

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I would like to set the same value to the locale environment variables: `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_ALL`, `LANG`.

I want to be able to set it directly on the interactive bash shell, something like this:

```
$ export LC_CTYPE=$LANG=$LC_ALL=C
```

This answer [Assign same value to multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651594/assign-same-value-to-multiple-variables) shows how to do it in a script, but not in the interactive shell.

Comment: The link you provided shows how to do it in a **PHP** script, not a shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference provided by you isn't a shell reference, it's a PHP example.

In shell, one way would be to use a loop:

```
for i in FOO BAR BAZ; do
  export $i=value
done
```

Answer (score 18):

```
export {LC_CTYPE,LANG,LC_ALL}=C
```

Comment: Hi Soner, anyway to accomplish this in 'ksh'.  Because, the syntax you provided is not supported by 'ksh'