# Unable to define variables as empty in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to define three empty variables through a foreach loop to make my code cleaner. This is what I've tried, however I see the error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: hi

```
foreach(['$hi','$bye','$hello'] as $key) {
    $key = "";
}

$hi .= "hello";
```

When I remove the foreach loop and simply define each empty variable one by one, like this, it works:

```
$hi = "";
$bye = "";
$hello = "";
```

Comment: why you used single quotes? you can use double quotes or leave it without quotes

Comment: @AnimeshSahu If I remove the quotes, it then says that all the variables are undefined.

Comment: PHP101 - Whenever you put something in quotes, it becomes a string. '$hi','$bye','$hello' are all strings so you can not pass them as variables to concat values to them.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to `$key`, not to the variable that's named by it. To indirect through a variable, you need to use `$$key`. But the value of the variable shouldn't include the `$`, just the variable name.

```
foreach (['hi', 'bye', 'hello'] as $key) {
    $$key = "";
}
$hi .= "hello";
```

However, if you ever find yourself using variable variables like this, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. You should probably be using an associative array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have strings which are saved in $key. So the value of $key is a string and you set it to "".

Later you want to append something to a variable you never used.

Try to remove the ' and write

```
foreach([$hi, $bye, $hello] as $key) {
```

Generally thats not the best way to initialise multiple variables. Try this

[Initializing Multiple PHP Variables Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651793/initializing-multiple-php-variables-simultaneously#9651795)

Comment: Oh brilliant, thanks for including the link to that answer as I think that's much simpler than using an array. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Easier way:

> list($hi, $bye, $hello) = "";

Comment: Is it more beneficial to use this than `$hi = $bye = $hello = "";`?

Comment: In case of List, variables go NULL when used string, actually `$hi = $bye = $hello = "";` is better.

Answer (score 0):

foreach creates a new array variable in memory, so you only clear these values inside the array in memory which is useless out of the foreach sentence. the best way is:

```
$h1=$bye=$hello="";
```

I didn't think that a foreach process will work more fast than a Simple equal (=), foreach function uses more CPU resources than a simple =. That's because the math CPU exists.